# Basic How to AJAX to mongoDB server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

Can someone give me a simple example of how to make a ajax request to pull data from my database? I want to check if a user exist before creating the new one I am using mlabs and trying to get a basic idea of how to access it through javascript. And stackoverflow is still making me type more and more because its "mostly code". So The test of this paragraph is just me filling out as much as it takes to allow me to post my question.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var app = express();

// Connect to the database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://josh:josh@ds163020.mlab.com:63020/imgup');

// Create schema
var users = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
email: String
});

// Create Model
var User = mongoose.model('User', users);

//Add a user to database
var josh = User({
username: 'josh',
password: 'josh',
email: 'email@email.com'
}).save(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('User Added');
});
```

Comment: Are you using routes to get your User data?

Comment: I am not sure, I think this might be out of my skill level, but I am trying to challenge myself. I know I need to use routes, but I am not sure how to do it. I was looking for a basic example, but I understand if there isn't one to give.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For making an Ajax request you need to have a route.
Since you are doing everything manually,you could check if the users exits at the server file itself:

```
User.findOne({email:'email@email.com'},function(err,user){
  if(err)
   console.log(err);
  if(user)
   console.log("user already exists");
  else{
   User({
    username: 'josh',
    password: 'josh',
    email: 'email@email.com'
    }).save(function(err){
   if(err) throw err;
     console.log('User Added');
   });
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I will look into the routing, I assume it would be a form that makes a get or post request to that route?

Comment: Cool. And, yes exactly!